# How to extract query parameters using switchMap

Tags: angular, angular-material

In Angular component, in .ts
I want to extract query parameters and pas these params to store action.

```
    this.route.queryParams
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.store.select(selectSelectedLoan)),
        tap((selectedLoan) => this.store.dispatch(AccountActions.addNewPaymentMethod({
          borrowerId: selectedLoan.borrowerId, accountNumber: selectedLoan.accountNumber,
          tokenId: this.tokenId, fundingAccount: this.fundingAccount, nickName: this.nickName, singleUse: this.singleUse,
          expiryDate: this.expiryDate, fundingAccountSubType: this.fundingAccountSubType, ssoKey: this.ssoKey
        }))),
        tap((status) => this.router.navigate(['./account/payments'])),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscriber$)
      )
      .subscribe();
```

Currently I have defined all the variables in component. I want to replace those variables with params values directly.
E.g. - this.nickName -> params.nickName

Something like

```
this.route.queryParams
    .pipe(
           switchMap(params => extract data you need),
           switchMap(extracted data => dispatch action)
```

Comment: you can use `map` instead of `switchMap` if you are not switching observables.

Comment: Why are you navigating trought `tap`....???

Answer (score 0):

Just use `map` instead of `switchMap` to transform `X` to `Y`

```
this.route.queryParams
    .pipe(
           map(params => {
               a:params.getSomehowA,
               b:params.getSomehowB
            }),
           switchMap(data => data is {a:valueA,b:valueB}, use it)
```